# How to delete the localy installed version of npx command?

Tags: node.js, npm-install, npx

When I execute a command with npx, npx propose me to install a version locally.

Example

> npx matcha-stock -s=MSFT

If the version is updated on npm.org, npx gives me only the version installed locally and doesn't check if an updated version exists.

If I execute

> npx matcha-stock@latest -s=MSFT

I get the latest version of the tool.

But, if I execute again

npx matcha-stock -s=MSFT

I got the previous installation.

Question: How to uninstall, clear the cache of the locally installed version of the command ?

#npx #NPM

Answer (score 12):

The dependencies of each of these commands are stored in a cache at `.npm/_npx/*/node_modules`, when I tried blowing all those away it worked.

Finding which one to delete

```
ls ~/.npm/_npx/*/node_modules | grep matcha-stock
```

Just deleting them all

```
rm -r ~/.npm/_npx/
```

Comment: or on Windows, apparently at C:\Users\{YourUserName}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\

Comment: in the `_npx` sub folder the packages are stored in a folders using random id as their names. If you want to delete a specific package. then you can navigate to each folder and check the package.json and find out which package you are currently looking at.

Comment: Super handy, ty!

Comment: For Windows, the folder is different than what @Thomas posted.  Maybe it's changed.   On my system you have to go to the _npx subfolder.   You can use this `%localappdata%\npm-cache\_npx`